# Servicestack License for Redis framework

Tags: asp.net, redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

I am using AWS Redis (Elastic Cache) for my web site, which is developed using ASP.NET MVC. To connect with Redis i am using ServiceStack.Redis framework.
I have moved this to production. But unfortunately, i am getting error like

> The free-quota limit on '6000 Redis requests per hour' has been
>   reached.

So i have checked with their site, they are saying we need to buy licence. They providing the licence per developer. **What is developer here??**. Here i have 4 web server and one load balance. So **how much i need to buy**. And **where i need to specify this licence in my code??**

Comment: You should [email ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/pricing#faq) for any licensing questions, but "a developer" is any developer contributing code to a licensed ServiceStack project, if it's just you then that's only 1 license. All developer licenses are royalty-free which allows any licensed developer to deploy to unlimited servers and at no additional cost.

Comment: You must choose between paying for a license or refactor to use a real open-source solution like StackExchange.Redis

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the answer you're looking for, but if you have not considered it, you may want have a look at StackExchange.Redis client. It is free and open source https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis.

Comment: Yes! i know about this.  But i have completed my development with servicestack.

Comment: That's not an option if you are using Sentinel though. `csredis` supports it, but only version 2.8